# Updating m4 on mac OS X 10.6.8

Tags: macos, m4

I'm trying to upgrade m4 from version 1.4.6 (the version that comes with OS X 10.6.8) to 1.4.16. I've installed with homebrew, and I've also built from source into /usr/local/ (and edited /etc/paths to put /usr/local above /usr), but the system version still seems to take precedence.

Specifically, if I type `m4 --version', I get`GNU M4 1.4.6 `, but if I type`/usr/local/bin/m4 --versoin`, I get`m4 (GNU M4) 1.4.16 `. How do I set the new version as the default version?

...ultimately, I'd like to update autoconf and automake. Is there anything else I should know about installing them?

Answer (score 1):

When you type just `m4` at the prompt, your shell looks through the `PATH` variable to locate the command.  You just need to prepend `/usr/local/bin` to your path.  For example, in `~/.bashrc`, you can simply do:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Note that this may lead to the directory appearing multiple times in the PATH.  You can avoid that with something like:

```
echo $PATH | tr : \\n | grep -q '^/usr/local/bin$' || PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```